# Can I access shared project in BIM360 FIELD?

Tags: autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

I created new project in BIM360 using BIM360 user account. (say account1)

[image: Create project in BIM360 -img source: https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/ENU/BIM360D-Administration/images/create_project_profile.png]
*Snapshot 1*

Then activated BIM360 Field Service.

[image: Activate services in BIM360.]

*Snapshot 2*

Then I shared that Project with other BIM360 user account. (Say Account2)
Now I'm trying to access that shared project using Account2 in BIM360. I was able to access the Project in BIM360 DOCS Also I was able to create new Daily Update in it though BIM360 DOCS-> Field Management.

But the shared project isn't visible in Account2's [BIM360 FIELD UI](https://bim360field.autodesk.com/).

I was trying to create new daily in shared project using Account2 credentials with help of [daily_updates API](https://bim360field.autodesk.com/apidoc/index.html#api/v1/daily_updates_method_3). But I wasn't able to access that shared project in [Projects API](https://bim360field.autodesk.com/apidoc/index.html#mobile_api_method_3) using Account2.

Is it the expected behavior?
Or did I miss something while sharing project?

Comment: Which kind of BIM360 Field service did you create? With my experience, only the project activated with the classical field service is visible in the https://bim360field.autodesk.com

Comment: Refer snapshot 2, I activated BIM 360 Field service from there only.

Activated project is visible in Account1's bim360field.autodesk.com.
As it's shared with Account2's bim360, shouldn't it be visible in his bim360field.autodesk.com?

Comment: is this user (saying account2) a member of the shared Field project? If no, please add account2 to the project. Afterward, It should be visible.

Comment: Just curious, the BIM360 Field service is inactive in the snapshot2, and you said account1 is able to see it in Classical Field UI. With my experience, it should be activated as Classical Field.